# Tomcat 7 server won't start after suppressing a Library error

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I rather stupidly used "Quick Fix" on a couple of build path errors which occurred due to adding `common-i0` and `commons-fileupload` libraries. I think the fix was just to **suppress them possibly.**

I against better judgment just clicked next next. The errors went away but it did not fix my problem.

I now cannot start the tomcat server as I get the very uninformative error as seen below.[image]

Due to the lack of errors I really don't know what I should be doing to try and fix this error. Is there a way to back track all quick fixes?

Thanks